# ST_Split and looping problems PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am a total PostGIS noob, and am having trouble understanding the finer points of SQL syntax. I am trying to take a large set of line data and clip it with a polygon. I then want to create a new table with the lines that are in the polygon I used to clip. When I run this I receive 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "ST_Split"' I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax. I was hopping that some could explain to me what is wrong with this line of code. Additionally I hoping that some one could explain the looping and variable syntax. Coming form a python background it seems very complicated.

```
CREATE TABLE roads_clipped AS

ST_Split(
    (SELECT geom 
    FROM roads),
    (SELECT st_union 
    FROM iberian_peninsula)
);

CREATE TABLE roads_of_the_iberian_peninsula;

BEGIN
    FOR row IN 
        SELECT geom FROM roads_clipped
    LOOP
        IF ST_Contains(
                (SELECT st_union 
                FROM iberian_peninsula)
                ,row)
            THEN INSERT INTO roads_of_the_iberian_peninsula
                VALUES row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be

```
CREATE TABLE your_table AS (SELECT ST_Split(...));
```

Also `CREATE TABLE roads_of_the_iberian_peninsula;` doesn't make sense as there is no column definition.